# ByteString histogram

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Given a (strict) ByteString, what is the most efficient way to count how many of each possible byte it contains?

I see that `sort` is supposed to implemented as a counting sort - but there doesn't appear to be a way to access the associated counts. I also see that there's a `count` function, which counts the number of times a given byte appears. This gives me the following options:

- `map (\ b -> count b str) [0x00 .. 0xFF]`
- `map length . group . sort`
- Something with `fold*` and an `IntMap` of byte frequencies.

Which is likely to give me best performance?

Comment: `IntMap` is the best solution (especially for large strings).

Comment: @josejuan Based on what evidence?  Of the three mentioned in the question, the length/group/sort solution is actually much better.

Comment: Ok, ok, you are using `B.sort` that use... `unsafeCreate`! (to count) that's cheat! :D :D :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea of [dflemstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230461/dflemstr) is of course right, but since you want the best performance, you need to use unchecked access to the `ByteString` as well as to the counting array, like

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeRead, unsafeWrite)
import Data.Array.Unboxed

import Data.Word

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString.Unsafe

histogram :: ByteString -> UArray Word8 Int
histogram bs = runSTUArray $ do
    hist <- newArray (0, 255) 0
    let l = BS.length bs
        update b = do
            o <- unsafeRead hist b
            unsafeWrite hist b (o+1)
        loop i
            | i < 0     = return hist
            | otherwise = do
                update $ fromIntegral (bs `unsafeIndex` i)
                loop (i-1)
    loop (l-1)
```

That makes a considerable difference, according to `criterion` (building a histogram of a 200000 long `ByteString`):

```
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 1.667687 us (320001 iterations)
found 3078 outliers among 319999 samples (1.0%)
  1947 (0.6%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 40.43765 ns (14 iterations)

benchmarking dflemstr
mean: 21.42852 ms, lb 21.05213 ms, ub 21.77954 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.873897 ms, lb 1.719565 ms, ub 2.038779 ms, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 74.820%
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking unsafeIndex
mean: 312.6447 us, lb 304.3425 us, ub 321.0795 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 42.86886 us, lb 39.64363 us, ub 46.52899 us, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 88.342%
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

(I changed dflemstr's code to also use `runSTUArray` and return a `UArray Word8 Int` to have uiform return values, that doesn't make a big difference in running time, though.)

Comment: OOC, how does `count` compare?

Comment: Wait a minute or two, haven't tested yet.

Comment: `mean: 41.18654 ms, lb 41.05191 ms, ub 41.39745 ms, ci 0.950` for `chistogram bs = array (0,255) [(b, B.count b bs) | b <- [0 .. 255]]`. I can imagine one could speed that up, but since it has to do 256 passes over the `ByteString`, that can't do too well.

Comment: I understand, but I feel some "Haskell disappointed" when I see `unsafe`... :/

Comment: @josejuan In this case, it's only an unfortunate choice of name, it should have been `unsafeIfYouDidn'tCheckTheValidityOfIndexButPerfectlyFineIfYouDidRead/Write/Index`, but that is too long. It's an entirely different kind of "unsafe" than `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielFischer for your reply, I'm a (4ever) rookie and must investigate it (but not smell right :D :D)

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient method probably involves using a mutable array for storing the counts. This is potentially one of the most efficient O(n) solutions available:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST

import Data.Array.ST

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as ByteString

import Data.Word

byteHistogram :: ByteString -> [Int]
byteHistogram bs = runST $ do
  histogram <- newArray (minBound, maxBound) 0 :: ST s (STUArray s Word8 Int)
  forM_ (ByteString.unpack bs) $ \ byte ->
    readArray histogram byte >>= return . (+1) >>= writeArray histogram byte
  getElems histogram
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you can guess or you can make a program and measure it - the results can surprise you.

```
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.IntMap.Strict as I
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main
import System.Entropy
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.Word

main = do
    bs <- getEntropy 1024
    defaultMain [ bench "map count" $ nf mapCount bs
                , bench "map group sort" $ nf mapGroup bs
                , bench "fold counters" $ nf mapFoldCtr bs
                , bench "vCount" $ nf vectorCount bs
                ]

-- O(n*m) (length of bytestring, length of list of element being counted up)
-- My guess: bad
mapCount :: ByteString -> [Int]
mapCount bs = Prelude.map (`B.count` bs) [0x00..0xFF]

-- Notice that B.sort uses counting sort, so there's already lots of
-- duplicate work done here.
-- O() isn't such a big deal as the use of lists - likely allocation and
-- large constant factors.
mapGroup :: ByteString -> [Int]
mapGroup = Prelude.map Prelude.length . Prelude.map B.unpack . B.group . B.sort

mapFoldCtr :: ByteString -> [Int]
mapFoldCtr bs  = I.elems $ B.foldl' cnt I.empty bs
 where
 cnt :: I.IntMap Int -> Word8 -> I.IntMap Int
 cnt m k = I.insertWith (+) (fromIntegral k) 1 m

 -- create (do { v <- new 2; write v 0 'a'; write v 1 'b'; return v })
vectorCount :: B.ByteString -> [Int]
vectorCount bs = V.toList $ V.create $ do
        v <- M.new 256
        Prelude.mapM_ (\i -> M.unsafeWrite v i 0) [0..255]
        Prelude.mapM_ (\i -> M.unsafeRead v (fromIntegral i) >>= M.unsafeWrite v (fromIntegral i) . (+1) ) (B.unpack bs)
        return v
```

And the results (shortened) reflect amazingly well on map group sort but leave the unboxed mutable vector/array style solution unsurprisingly in the lead:

```
benchmarking map count
mean: 308.7067 us, lb 307.3562 us, ub 310.5099 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.942305 us, lb 6.269114 us, ub 10.08334 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking map group sort
mean: 43.03601 us, lb 42.93492 us, ub 43.15815 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 567.5979 ns, lb 486.8838 ns, ub 666.0098 ns, ci 0.950

benchmarking fold counters
mean: 191.5338 us, lb 191.1102 us, ub 192.0366 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 2.370183 us, lb 1.995243 us, ub 2.907595 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking vCount
mean: 12.98727 us, lb 12.96037 us, ub 13.02261 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 156.6505 ns, lb 123.6789 ns, ub 198.4892 ns, ci 0.950
```

Oddly, when I increase the bytestring size to 200K, as Daniel used, then map/group/sort clocks in at ~250us while the vector solution takes over 500us:

```
benchmarking map count
mean: 5.796340 ms, lb 5.788830 ms, ub 5.805126 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 41.65349 us, lb 35.69293 us, ub 48.39205 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking map group sort
mean: 260.7405 us, lb 259.2525 us, ub 262.4742 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 8.247289 us, lb 7.127576 us, ub 9.371299 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking fold counters
mean: 3.915101 ms, lb 3.892415 ms, ub 4.006287 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 201.7632 us, lb 43.13063 us, ub 469.8170 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking vCount
mean: 556.5588 us, lb 545.4895 us, ub 567.9318 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 57.44888 us, lb 51.22270 us, ub 65.91105 us, ci 0.950
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1.0%)
variance introduced by outliers: 80.038%
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

But that variance is tremendous - perhaps some playing with heap sizes would make that go away (in the benchmark program at least), but not quickly or easily for me.

Answer (score 2):

(Do not take it very seriously)

The (actual) fastest solution, and pure FP solution is this... nearly:

```
data Hist = Hist {v00 :: Int, v01 :: Int {- , v02 :: Int, ... -} }

emptyHist :: Hist
emptyHist = Hist 0 0 {- 0 0 ... -}

foldRecord :: B.ByteString -> [Int]
foldRecord = histToList . B.foldl' cnt emptyHist
  where histToList (Hist x00 x01 {- x02 ... -}) = [x00, x01 {- , x02, ... -}]
        cnt (Hist !x00 !x01)    0x00      = Hist (x00 + 1) x01 {- x02 ... -}
        cnt (Hist !x00 !x01) {- 0x01 -} _ = Hist x00 (x01 + 1) {- x02 ... -}
        {- ... -}
```

Using @Thomas benchmarks runs in 11.67 us (the previous fastest `vCount` take 14.99 us in my machine).

The problem is when `cnt` is splitted into 256 posible patterns (a full equivalent code using `lens` is [here](https://gist.github.com/josejuan/5789847)).

The compiler is slow selecting the proper pattern (left side of `cnt`) or incrementing (right side of `cnt`) but I think should generate efficient code (at least, equal efficience of two patterns).

(Using 256 `cnt` patterns and 256 `Hist` values take 1.35 ms!!!)

(In my machine, `map group sort` take 42 us, behind `vCount` alternative)